# Is there ready S.M.A.R.T monitoring toolkit for NVME disks (exporter,source,board)?

Tags: monitoring, smart, nvme

I already found node_exporter and grafana board for HDD S.M.A.R.T. Can You please get advice or url for ready exporter or other toolkit?

I'm trying to wrote my own "messy" text exporter for prometheus, but I think that there must be ready solution.

```
nvme list | grep dev | cut -d " " -f1 | cut -d "/" -f3 | xargs -I % sh -c 'nvme smart-log /dev/% | tr -d " ."| sed "s/:/{disk=\"\/dev\/%\"} /g"| sed "s/ C//g"' | grep -v "Log"| tr -d "%" | sed "s/C$//g"
```

Answer (score 1):

`smartctl` added nvme support in versions >= 6.5.

`nvme smart-log <device> -o json` should provide the information you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, is there ready solution for board and exporter?

Comment: > nvme smart-log <device> -o json  - is it mean that prometheus support and can parse json out of box?